# How to search entire Linux server files containing specific text?

Tags: linux, text, grep, directory, find

To search specific text (IP-address in my example) inside folders and sub-folders i use something like that:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -liz '45.20.20.77' {} \;
```

or

```
grep -rnwl '/' -e "45.20.20.77" 2>/dev/null
```

But i have problems when i `cd /` on CentOS running on Vultr with `root` user:

- a lot of `"Permission Denied"` errors (solved using `2>/dev/null`)
- it freezes when some system folder reached like `proc`, `sys`

On my Vultr server after `/var/lib/cloud/instances/` everything freezes.
Is that possible to set some timeout if no answer from some folder or file? I know i can use `find ! -path "./proc/*"` but i want something that can automatically scan all entire server without manual directory exclude.

Comment: you can also use `-s` option to suppress error messages... excluding directories you don't want is right way to do imo, you can alias/function your commands so that you can reuse them easily

Comment: also, you might want to use `-F` to specify `'45.20.20.77'` as a literal string as opposed to regex, which will speed up things a bit... no point in using `-n` option along with `-l` or `-i` option when you are searching for just numbers... also, why `-z` option? is the search string spread over multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kostya572 !

I think you will have to study your problems a little more, to get a really automatic solution. So, here is just some brainstorming. I hope that it helps.

You certainly already know that, but the use of `2> /dev/null` probably doesn't solve any error, just hides it.

Maybe these errors are related to files with spaces in between, like `Program Files`, as the Posix utilities have chronical problems with file names with spaces inside them. In this case, they will most of the time think that this expression describes two directories, instead of one. And one of them is named `Program`, and the other `Files`.

If there's neither a directory named `Program` nor one named `Files`, the error msg will be  `Permission denied`, as you said.

One idea is to segregate some of the problems. For instance, you can separate the `find`-ing of files from their `grep`-ing. For instance, with `xargs`.

If you understand what tool is is the culprit for the freezing, you could use `timeout` (run `man timeout` to learn more about it) to control the time this tool can take.

In any case, you could run a `find / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d` to get control of the 1st level of the file system. Then you can issue a find for each of these 1st level directories.

Good luck !